# Casting between Microsoft.SharePoint.Client and Microsoft.SharePoint types

Tags: csom

Is there any trivial casting between `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and `Microsoft.SharePoint` types?
Such as `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.BaseType` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseType`, 
or such as
`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. These are completely different types, and even the whole assemblies are supposed to be used in different scenarios.

- `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.*` classes form the Client-Side Object Model, which, in fact, means your code interacts with SharePoint remotely, running outside any of SharePoint processes;
- `Microsoft.SharePoint.*.SP*` classes form the Server-Side Object Model, which works for code running *within* any of SharePoint processes.

You shouldn't be mixing both in a single piece of code.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!